# Is there a better way to define these Angular/Ionic models?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, model

A new Angular/Ionic project I'm working on has many models defined in a single .model.ts file in the following way.

```
export class Order {
    constructor(
        public OrderId?: string,
        public Items?: string[],
    ) {}
}

export class OrderStatus {
    constructor(
        public OrderId?: string,
        public __str__: string,
    ) {}
}
```

And is imported in other files using

```
import { Order, OrderStatus } from 'src/app/.../models/orders/orders.model.ts';
```

which is a nice one-liner but i'm wondering wether if there's a better way load the models and structure directories/files.

I was thinking of implementing the following pattern:

```
'src/app/.../models/orders/order.model.ts';
'src/app/.../models/orders/order-status.model.ts';
```

Where each file has its corresponding `Order` and `OrderStatus` classes defined. This seems to me a better way of abstracting each models since now the file name directly correspond to the class defined inside; a one-to-one relation is stablished between file and model and.

My motivation for reshaping this file structure is for facilitating future escalations of the project.

A drawback I do foresee is having to use two lines of code when importing these two models in the same component/service. Where i would once import the two classes like this

```
import { Order, OrderStatus } from 'src/app/.../models/orders/orders.model.ts';
```

i would now have to import them like this

```
import { Order } from 'src/app/.../models/orders/order.model.ts';
import { OrderStatus } from 'src/app/.../models/orders/order-status.model.ts';
```

I already googled about this and couldn't find any documentation about best practices in model defining for Ionic projects, which is why I'm posting here with a logic approach I thought of.

Am I going in the right direction?
Should I leave the current structure alone and focus on something else?
Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I did some more digging on the Angular Style Guide (https://angular.io/guide/styleguide) and according to the Rule Of One it is better to have just one class in the file.

> A single component can be the default export for its file which facilitates lazy loading with the router.